# Command line parameter not accepting as arguments properly in Golang program

Tags: go, concurrency, backend, channel

I am new to Golang and was following a tutorial online about making a simple quiz application using the command line terminal. However, when I run the code on my machine, after the 1st question, the rest of the questions come in pairs and it is not accepting my answer to each question anymore.

Sample screenshot:

[image: program output on vscode terminal]

The flow of the program is quite simple -

1. Take input questions from a local csv file
2. Print each question and take user input for the answer
3. Maintain count of correct answers and display them at the end.

The csv file is quite short too -

```
70+22,92
63+67,130
91+72,163
74+61,135
81+6,87
```

Here is the complete program -

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // 1. input the name of the file
    fName := flag.String("f", "quiz.csv", "path of csv file")
    // 2. set the duration of timer
    timer := flag.Int("t", 30, "timer for the quiz")
    flag.Parse()
    // 3. pull the problems from the file  (calling our problem puller)
    problems, err := problemPuller(*fName)
    // 4. handle the error
    if err != nil {
        exit(fmt.Sprintf("something went wrong: %s", err.Error()))
    }
    // 5. create a variable to count our correct answers
    correctAns := 0
    // 6. using the duration of the timer, we want to initialize the timer
    tObj := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(*timer) * time.Second)
    ansC := make(chan string)
    // 7. loop through the problems, print the questions, we'll accept the answers
    problemLoop: 
        for i, p := range problems {
            var answer string
            fmt.Printf("Problem %d: %s =", i+1, p.question)

            go func() {
                fmt.Scanf("%s", &answer)
                ansC <- answer
            }()
            select {
                case <- tObj.C:
                    fmt.Println()
                    break problemLoop
                case iAns := <- ansC:
                    if iAns == p.answer {
                        correctAns++
                    }
                    if i == len(problems)-1 {
                        close(ansC)
                    }
            }
        }
    // 8. calculate and print out the result
    fmt.Printf("Your result is %d out of %d\n", correctAns, len(problems))
    fmt.Printf("Press enter to exit")
    <- ansC
}

func problemPuller(fileName string) ([]problem, error) {
    // read all the problems from the quiz.csv

    // 1. open the file
    if fObj, err := os.Open(fileName); err == nil {
        // 2. we will create new reader
        csvR := csv.NewReader(fObj)
        // 3. it will need to read the file
        if cLines, err := csvR.ReadAll(); err == nil {
            // 4. call the parseProblem function
            return parseProblem(cLines), nil
        } else {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error in reading data in csv from %s file; %s", fileName, err.Error())
        }
    } else {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error in opening the file %s file; %s", fileName, err.Error())
    }
}

func parseProblem(lines [][]string) []problem {
    // go over the lines and parse them based on the problem struct
    r := make([] problem, len(lines))
    for i := 0; i < len(lines); i++ {
        r[i] = problem {
            question: lines[i][0],
            answer: lines[i][1],
        }
    }
    return r
}

type problem struct {
    question string
    answer   string
}

func exit(msg string) {
    fmt.Println(msg)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

I tried going through each line of code but I am unable to solve it. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I gave this a try, worked perfectly for me, "go run main.go"
Problem 1: 70+22 =92
Problem 2: 63+67 =130
Problem 3: 91+72 =163
Problem 4: 74+61 =135
Problem 5: 81+6 =87
Your result is 5 out of 5
Press enter to exit. What is the go version/ platform you are running this on? In the CSV file what is the line terminator LF or CRLF?

Comment: [bufio.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) is an alternative for reading string values which doesn't behave inconsistently with regards to newline (to my knowledge, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on Windows (running in `Command Prompt`). But there is not issue on Linux.

The following change will fix the issue:

```
  go func() {
-   fmt.Scanf("%s", &answer)
+   fmt.Scanln(&answer)
    ansC <- answer
  }()
```

This is a known issue reported as [fmt: Scanf works differently on Windows and Linux #23562](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23562). And there is a [pending fix](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/110595) for it too. Unfortunately, the CL has unresolved comments and is blocked for a long time.

Comment: I have updated the answer to add a link to the reported issue.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. This was certainly very helpful. I hope the team provides a fix soon.